# Get permalink to page?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I know this is going to be simple but I can't work it out.

I want to create a nav in the footer listing each page and it's child pages.

It will look something like this

```
    <ul>
      <li><a href="parent.html">Parent</a></li>
      <li><a href="childone.html">Child One</a></li>
      <li><a href="childtwo.html">Child Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="childthree.html">Child Three</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I'm using this code to do it.

```
    <div id="footerLinks">
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
            'parent' => 0,
            );
        $pages = get_pages($args);
        foreach($pages as $page){
            ?>
            <ul>
                <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $page->permalink; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title;?> </a> 
                </li>
                <?php  
                wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1&child_of='.$page->ID.'');
                ?>  
            </ul>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

My problem is getting the permalink to the parent page.

```
    <a href="<?php echo $page->permalink; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title;?> </a>
```

How do I get the permalink in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
<? echo get_permalink($page->post_parent); ?>
```